# How to intercept and log errors from WebRTC layer?

Tags: firefox, logging, webrtc

In my project I have console.log (and all other) overwritten in order to gather logs and periodically send them to the server. It is done by calling

```
window.console[consoleLevel] = customLogger
```

for all console log levels.

However, sometimes we observer this kind of errors coming from Webrtc layer of our application:

WebRTC: ICE failed, add a STUN server and see about:webrtc for more details.
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26glb.png)

This error won't be captured by our custom logger. Is there a way to capture this and all other similar messages?